# SQL Server 2008 R2 DMV - sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities - query usage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dependencies, dmv

I am trying to get all dependencies for a list of tables using the `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` DMV.

This query gives me the list of all tables:

```
SELECT TableName from FinalTableList;
```

This query gives the dependencies for TableA:

```
SELECT  referencing_entity_name
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.TableA', 'OBJECT') ;
```

I would like to combine the above 2 in a query or procedure so that I can get all dependencies in the following format:

```
TableA  Dependency1
        Dependency2
        Dependency3
TableB  Dependency1
        Dependency2
...................
```

How should the query be framed?

Answer (score 5):

This is a great example of where you want to use `cross apply`.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT  tablename, referencing_entity_name
FROM (select 'information_schema.columns' as tablename, 'object' as type) t cross apply
     sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(t.tablename, t.type)
```

In the first subquery (which is called `t`), you can just list all the pairs of arguments.  Then, `cross apply` will run the function on each of them.

Comment: Important:  Requires CONTROL permission on the referenced object. When the referenced entity is a partition function, CONTROL permission on the database is required.  (Otherwise, null resultset will be returned.)