# SQL Server - How to create custom JSON from SELECT with "key": derived from GROUP BY clause

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2019, json-query

I am trying to get nice overview of dependencies of tables.

My query looks like this: (if there is something better than `STRING_AGG`, please let me know)

```sql
SELECT 
    [schema] = referencing_schema_name,
    [objects] = JSON_QUERY('["' 
        + STRING_AGG(STRING_ESCAPE(referencing_entity_name, 'json'), '","') 
        + '"]')
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (
    'dbo.C_Table',
    'OBJECT' ) re
GROUP BY referencing_schema_name
FOR JSON PATH;
```

And it produces output like:

```json
[
    {
        "schema": "dbo",
        "objects": [
            "C_Table"
        ]
    },
    {
        "schema": "bcd",
        "objects": [
            "get_AmazingDataById",
            "get_EvenMoreAmazingDataById"
        ]
    }
]
```

So grouping works, but I'd like to have it "nicer" :D and more readable like this:

```json
[
   "dbo": [
       "C_Table"
   ],
   "bcd": [
       "get_AmazingDataById",
       "get_EvenMoreAmazingDataById"
   ]
]
```

Do you have some suggestions for creating an array and using the value of `group by` as a key for that array?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support either `JSON_AGG` or `JSON_OBJ_AGG`, both of which would have made this query significantly simpler.

You can just hack the whole thing with `STRING_AGG` a second time.

```sql
SELECT
    '[' +
    STRING_AGG(
      '{"' +
      STRING_ESCAPE(referencing_schema_name, 'json') +
      '":' +
      re.jsonArray
    , ',') +
    ']'
FROM (
    SELECT
      re.referencing_schema_name,
      jsonArray = '["' 
        + STRING_AGG(STRING_ESCAPE(re.referencing_entity_name, 'json'), '","') 
        + '"]'
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.C_Table', 'OBJECT' ) re
    GROUP BY
      re.referencing_schema_name
) re;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae73eff2331ae8a3c915c4bb05cb1602)

Comment: Nice example with db fiddle! So just kinda cumbersome creating arrays and putting it together. I've come up with one solution combining STRING_AGG with JSON_MODIFY. I'll post it here also. Btw, don't you know if I can get referencing entities from more tables? I would have them in temporal table or somewhere and use them in this select? I tried `cross join #mObjects` or naive `where @name = (select  objName from #mObjects` but it didn't work. It accepts only simple variable name afaik.

Comment: Sounds like you might need `where re.referencing_entity_name in (select  objName from #mObjects)` or something like that, maybe a join. I suggest you make a new question for that.

Comment: After some searching I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690879/sql-server-2008-r2-dmv-sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-query-usage) `CROSS_APPLY` it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using json_Query and JSON_Modify combination as given example.

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)



SET @jsonInfo=N'
{"68c4":["yes"], "c8ew":["0","1"], "p6i4":["London","Frankfurt","Tokyo"]}'
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(
JSON_MODIFY(@jsonInfo, '$.City', JSON_QUERY(@jsonInfo, '$.p6i4')),
'$.p6i4', NULL)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this is nice, but its hard coded values. I am interested in using it in a select statement and I gave kinda precise example. Your example is also kinda hard to read due to formatting but thank you for showing nested json_modify although I think it will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with combination of `JSON_MODIFY` and `STRING_AGG`

```sql
DECLARE @out NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{}';
SELECT
 @out = JSON_MODIFY(
          @out,
          '$.' + aa.[schema],
          aa.[entities]
)
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        [schema]    = referencing_schema_name,
        [entities]  = JSON_QUERY(
            '["' 
            + STRING_AGG(
                STRING_ESCAPE(referencing_entity_name, 'json'),
                '","' )
            + '"]')
        FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities (
            'dbo.C_Table',
            'OBJECT' 
        ) re
        GROUP BY referencing_schema_name
) aa

select @out
```

I don't know what approach is better but working with JSON output is kinda pain in SQL Server.